# LightGBM max number of categories for Categorical features

Tags: python, categorical-data, gbm, lightgbm

Suppose that I have a dataset with a categorical variable encoded to int.
In the train function of lightgbm, I declare this variable as categorical

```
lgb.train(..., categorical_feature=['my_categorical_feature'], ...)
```

What is the maximum number of different categories that lightGBM can handle ?

Is it related to the max_bin parameter?
if yes, what happens if max_bin is set to 32 and the maximum value of 'my_categorical_feature' is 256 000 ?

Thanks

Comment: Question answered in LightGBM github : [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/issues/1279)